# Can we use JSDoc @this when passing a function literal as an argument

Tags: jsdoc

With JSDoc, I know you can use `@this` when declaring a function with

```js
/** @this {{foo: string}} */
const myFunc = function() {
  console.log(this.bar) // this will NOT type-check
  return this.foo // this will type-check
};
```

I'd like to be able to do the same when passing a function literal as an argument. This would look something like:

```js
functionDefinedSomewhereElse(/** @this {{foo: string}} */ function() {
  return this.foo // this will NOT type-check
});
```

The above code does not work though…

Is this even possible ?